# Access 2002 without outlook send emails

Tags: email-attachments, ms-access-2002

I developed desktop application which generates bunch of reports.

I want to add functionality to send that report via email.

The only problem is, not all clients using outlook for sending emails.

Is there any other way to send emails using my own SMTP server?

NOTE: Application build in Access2002